# Parse curl response from SOAP

Tags: php, curl, soap

I successfully get response from soap webservice using php curl. I would like to know how can I parse the curl response so that I got each value separately in other to save into database.

my codes:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxxxxx/WSAutorizaciones/WSAutorizacionLaboratorio.asmx?WSDL",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="https://arssenasa.gob.do/">
    <Cedula>001-0946651-5</Cedula>
    <Password>xxxxxxx</Password>
    <Proveedo>12077</Proveedo>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
    <ConsultarAfiliado xmlns="https://arssenasa.gob.do/">
    <TipoDocumento>2</TipoDocumento>
    <NumDocumento>021827151</NumDocumento>
    </ConsultarAfiliado>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type: text/xml"),
    ))
    ;

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
    echo $response;
    }
```

The result is displayed like this:

*8013-0000655-6021827151MARGARET ADIRASANTANA LORENZO DE CABRAL08CONTRIBUTIVO22/11/197346FEMENINO08*

the soap resonse is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
    <ConsultarAfiliadoResponse xmlns="https://arssenasa.gob.do/">
    <ConsultarAfiliadoResult>
    <Contrato>8</Contrato>
    <Cedula>013-0000655-6</Cedula>
    <Nss>021827151</Nss>
    <Nombres>MARGARET ADIRA</Nombres>
    <Apellidos>SANTANA LORENZO DE CABRAL</Apellidos>
    <IdEstado>0</IdEstado>
    <CodigoFamiliar>8</CodigoFamiliar>
    <IdRegimen xsi:nil="true" />
    <Regimen>CONTRIBUTIVO</Regimen>
    <FechaNacimiento>22/11/1973</FechaNacimiento>
    <Edad>46</Edad>
    <Sexo>FEMENINO</Sexo>
    <TipoDocumento>0</TipoDocumento>
    <CodigoAfiliado>8</CodigoAfiliado>
    <MensajeAfiliado />
    </ConsultarAfiliadoResult>
    </ConsultarAfiliadoResponse>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost a journey of research I finally get the correct way to do it :

```
   //The follow-up of my posting codes
    .
    .
    . 
   $response = curl_exec($curl);

   $response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
    $body = $xml->xpath('//soapBody ')[0];
    $array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$body), TRUE); 
    
    // in the case I want to grab only one data
    //echo  $array['ConsultarAfiliadoResponse']['ConsultarAfiliadoResult']['Cedula'];

    // to display all data in the array
    function dispaly_array_recursive($array_rec){
    if($array_rec){
    foreach($array_rec as $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
    dispaly_array_recursive($value);
    }else{
    echo $value.'<br>';
    }
    }
    }
    }
    dispaly_array_recursive($array);
```

No more problem to save into database now

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible example of how you could go about getting the XML elements from your SOAP response (below) using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which might be included in your PHP installation. Because I'm not sure what order of element data you need for the final output, you might need to rearrange the order of items in the output part below.

Also, in order for this to work, the `$soapResponse` variable in the code example needs to have **no extra space** before the start of the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line.

If you need to access other elements from the XML data, you should be able to do it with this pattern: `$result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->ElementNameHere`.

```
<?php

$soapResponse = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<ConsultarAfiliadoResponse xmlns="https://arssenasa.gob.do/">
<ConsultarAfiliadoResult>
<Contrato>8</Contrato>
<Cedula>013-0000655-6</Cedula>
<Nss>021827151</Nss>
<Nombres>MARGARET ADIRA</Nombres>
<Apellidos>SANTANA LORENZO DE CABRAL</Apellidos>
<IdEstado>0</IdEstado>
<CodigoFamiliar>8</CodigoFamiliar>
<IdRegimen xsi:nil="true" />
<Regimen>CONTRIBUTIVO</Regimen>
<FechaNacimiento>22/11/1973</FechaNacimiento>
<Edad>46</Edad>
<Sexo>FEMENINO</Sexo>
<TipoDocumento>0</TipoDocumento>
<CodigoAfiliado>8</CodigoAfiliado>
<MensajeAfiliado />
</ConsultarAfiliadoResult>
</ConsultarAfiliadoResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;

// Remove <soap></soap> related tag information to get plain XML content
$xmlContent = preg_replace('/<soap:.*?>\n/', '', $soapResponse);
$xmlContent = preg_replace('/<\/soap:.*?>\n?/', '', $xmlContent);

// Note: there is an error with the xsi:nil="true" part, but that can be
// suppressed with the following line. If you need to deal with this error,
// more info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$result = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlContent);

// Print out results
printf(
    "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s",
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Cedula,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Nss,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Nombres,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Apellidos,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->IdEstado,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->CodigoFamiliar,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Regimen,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->FechaNacimiento,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Edad,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->Sexo,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->TipoDocumento,
    $result->ConsultarAfiliadoResult->CodigoAfiliado
);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
$ php q22.php
013-0000655-6021827151MARGARET ADIRASANTANA LORENZO DE CABRAL08CONTRIBUTIVO22/11/197346FEMENINO08
```